# NgModule installing its own routes

Tags: angular, ng-modules

I am trying to figure out how to empoy `@NgModule` to better organize an Angular 2 modular app. In particular, I am interested in an NgModule *installing* its own routes into the app. Does anyone have a working example showing how to go about it?

Comment: `https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html#!#refactor-routes-to-a-_routing-module_`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say for example you have the home module.

```
-home
 -- home.component.ts
 -- home.component.html
 -- home.component.spec.ts
 -- home.routes.ts
```

// **home.routes.ts**

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { HomeComponent } from "./home.component";
const routes : Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  }
]

export default RouterModule.forChild(routes)
```

Then in your **AppModule** top level routes:

```
const routes : Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: 'app/modules/home/home.module',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  export class AppModule {
    constructor() {
   }
  }
```

With this your home module will be lazy loading.

Comment: Thanks. I fell into some kind of infinite loop somewhere, resulting in "stack exceeded" error, but that must have been my bad. Accepting the answer.